# How to add selected items to another multiple select in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to pass selected items to another list, so later on I can work with the final object/array?

student.component.ts:

```
students= [];
studentsFinal = [];

onGetStudents() {
    this.studentService.getStudents()
          .subscribe(
          (students: any[]) => this.students = students,
          (error) => console.log(error),
        );
      }
```

student.component.html:

```
        <h5>Final student list</h5>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select name="multiselect1" multiple class="form-control" name="myselecttsms1">
<option *ngFor="let studentFinal of studentsFinal" value="{{ studentFinal.Id 
}}">{{ studentFinal.Name }}</option>
            </select>
            <br>
        </div>

        <h5>Students</h5>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select name="multiselect2" multiple class="form-control" name="myselecttsms2">
                <option *ngFor="let student of students" value="{{ student.Id }}">{{ student.Name }}</option>
            </select>
            <br>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question little bit more? I didn't quite understand what you need to do.

Comment: yes, of course. I have two select item in my html (1 - list of students name, 2 - assigned students). Both are multiple options, so you can select more than one item. 
I have a button, when i click it, i want the selected student to pass to the another select list. Here is a picture: https://imgur.com/a/7v6OV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [ngModel] to your select and (ngModelChange)="selectedStudents($event)" event

```
<select [ngModel]="assignedStudents" (ngModelChange)="selectedStudents($event)" name="multiselect2" multiple class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let student of students" [ngValue]="student">{{ student.Name }}</option>
</select>
```

In your ts file add selectedStudents() function:

```
temporaryArray = [];
selectedStudents(students){
   this.temporaryArray = students;
}

//called on button click
assigne(){
   this.assignedStudents = this.temporaryArray;
}
```

Then

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let student of assignedStudents" [ngValue]="student">{{ student.Name }}</option>
</select>
```

Full example based on question and comments: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiselect-from-one-array-to-other

Comment: and how to trigger the addition?

Comment: It is automatically triggered, i updated answer to trigger addition manually.

Comment: i added the assigne() method to trigger manually, but when i click on an item, the another list gets populated with a blank item.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are using array of objects, it is a bit different, i created simple example with object https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdp7na and edited answer

Comment: no problem, thanks for the help.
What would be the easiest way, for the two way 'commmunication'? When I copy the opel car, i want to remove it in the first list, and be able to copy to the original list.

Comment: edited answer, hope it helps...if its correct please mark and upvote answer :D

Comment: thank you for the help! it works. I am Upvoting your answers now! one last question. if I have to use the selectedCars as an array or object array, how i am working with it?

console.log(this.selectedToRemove);

i get undefined.

Comment: i need the selected Ids and the Names

Comment: Selected or  assigned? If you select and dont click button then selected values are in temporary array. If you click assigned then selected values are moved to asssigned array.